# BOOL not recognized as data type (C...?)

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile an application from source code with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I've run into some problems.

When I try to compile, I get several errors related to BOOL being an undefined type. I've tried including winmindef.h and windef.h to no avail. Here's some of the function declarations in the code that throw errors:

```
void GetCheatName          ( int CheatNo, char * CheatName, int CheatNameLen );
BOOL LoadCheatExt          ( char * CheatName, char * CheatExt, int MaxCheatExtLen);
void RefreshCheatManager   ( void );
void SaveCheatExt          ( char * CheatName, char * CheatExt );
BOOL TreeView_GetCheckState(HWND hwndTreeView, HTREEITEM hItem);
BOOL TreeView_SetCheckState(HWND hwndTreeView, HTREEITEM hItem, BOOL fCheck);`
```

When I include the following in the .h file, the problem is still not resolved

```
#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE 1
#endif
#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE 0
#endif

typedef int BOOL;
```

If it helps, I am trying to compile PJ64, and may need to change some setting in order to compile, but I'm not sure which.

Any help at all is appreciated!

---UPDATE---

Here are the complete compile errors (I've omitted most of the warnings):

```
1>cl : Command line warning D9007: '/Gm' requires '/Zi or /ZI'; option ignored
1>  Cheat.c
1>Cheat.c(55): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'
1>Cheat.c(56): error C2059: syntax error: '{'
1>Cheat.c(233): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'WORD', possible loss of data
1>Cheat.c(326): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'WORD', possible loss of data
1>Cheat.c(346): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'WORD', possible loss of data
1>Cheat.c(982): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'
1>Cheat.c(998): error C2059: syntax error: '{'
1>Cheat.c(999): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>Cheat.c(1012): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
```

The complete code for the project I am trying to compile can be found [here](http://www.pj64-emu.com/downloads/project64/source-code/).

This is -part- of the code that was compiled and threw the above errors. I've left the vast majority of the code out because it is too lengthy to include here. I've left comments indicating which lines threw errors.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <windef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "cheats.h"
#include "cpu.h"
#include "resource.h"

#define UM_CHECKSTATECHANGE     (WM_USER + 100)
#define UM_CHANGECODEEXTENSION  (WM_USER + 101)
#define IDC_MYTREE              0x500

#define MaxCheats               300

#define SelectCheat             1
#define EditCheat               2
#define NewCheat                3 

HWND hManageWindow = NULL;
HWND hSelectCheat, hAddCheat, hCheatTree;
CHEAT_CODES Codes[MaxCheats];
int NoOfCodes;

void GetCheatName          ( int CheatNo, char * CheatName, int CheatNameLen );
BOOL LoadCheatExt          ( char * CheatName, char * CheatExt, int MaxCheatExtLen);
void RefreshCheatManager   ( void );
void SaveCheatExt          ( char * CheatName, char * CheatExt );
BOOL TreeView_GetCheckState(HWND hwndTreeView, HTREEITEM hItem); //(line 55, error thrown.)
BOOL TreeView_SetCheckState(HWND hwndTreeView, HTREEITEM hItem, BOOL fCheck); //(line 56)

LRESULT CALLBACK ManageCheatsProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );

void ApplyCheats (void) {
    //lots 'o code
}


BOOL CheatActive (char * Name) {
    //more code
}

LRESULT CALLBACK CheatsCodeExProc (HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    //Too much code to contain in this post...
}

LRESULT CALLBACK CheatsCodeQuantProc (HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    //code
}

//Because of the inmensity of code, I will skip to the lines that throw errors.

BOOL TreeView_GetCheckState(HWND hwndTreeView, HTREEITEM hItem) { //line 982, error thrown.
    //code here
}

BOOL TreeView_SetCheckState(HWND hwndTreeView, HTREEITEM hItem, BOOL fCheck) //line 999, error thrown
{ //line 1000, error thrown
    //Lots o code
} // line 1013, error thrown
```

If more code is desired, I'll gladly post!

Comment: sorry,  I tried to include windef.h, that didn't fix it, nor did including winmindef.h

Comment: Any reason you can't just use the standard/correct `bool` type rather than that ugly typedef/macro/whatever `BOOL`? And defining `true` and `false` - eeew, why?  This code looks to me like pretty bad C - please upgrade it to *good* C++ :)

Comment: Have you tried `WinDef.h`?

Comment: @tadman: If `windef.h` didn't work, I don't think `WinDef.h` would work either. (Most) Windows filesystems are case-insensitive.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: It might be necessary to use `BOOL` for compatibility with other Windows code that uses it. (That's the *only* excuse to use `BOOL` rather than `bool` in C++.)

Comment: [Microsoft says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) that `BOOL` is defined in `WinDef.h`, as `typedef int BOOL;`. You say (but only in a comment) that you tried including `windef.h`. Are you certain you did so correctly? Try compiling a small standalone C++ program that uses `#include <WinDef.h>` and refers to `BOOL`. And update your question to show code where you actually do include `WinDef.h`. Also, include the exact (copy-and-pasted) error message in the question. As it stands, you're asking us to debug code that we can't see.

Comment: @Keith Sure, that's a reason. I never said there were no reasons. I actually *asked* "why use BOOL". And I'd like to know OP's reason in this case.

Comment: Is there something in the PJ64 source that's doing funny stuff with BOOL?

Comment: Your code has `WinMinDef.h` which is perhaps missing this key thing.

Comment: Those errors don't say anything about `BOOL` not being recognized.

Comment: Missing BOOL errors. Can you give lines 50 - 55 in file cheat.c?

Comment: Don't define these things yourself, instead figure out how to include the right header

Comment: Note that while this is tagged 'C++' the file type is '.c'.

Comment: @kfsone true! I may have tagged this wrong.

Comment: @M.M it doesn't seem to make a difference if I include the correct .h file or not. It's quite puzzling.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I am not sure. I have asked questions on the forums at the PJ64 website and haven't heard anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked the code you gave a link to.

`BOOL` type is properly included. To check that you can compile `Cheat.c` with `/P` option.

All the problems are caused by upgrade of the project from Visual Studio 6 to Visual Studio 2015.

If you will investigate the pre-processor ouput you will see the transformation:

```
BOOL TreeView_GetCheckState(HWND hwndTreeView, HTREEITEM hItem); //(line 55, error thrown.)
BOOL TreeView_SetCheckState(HWND hwndTreeView, HTREEITEM hItem, BOOL fCheck); //(line 56)
```

pre-processed to:

```
BOOL ((((UINT)(SendMessageA((HWND hwndTreeView), (0x1100 + 39), (WPARAM)(HTREEITEM hItem), 0xF000))) >> 12) -1);
BOOL { TVITEMA _ms_TVi; _ms_TVi.mask = 0x0008; _ms_TVi.hItem = (HTREEITEM hItem); _ms_TVi.stateMask = (0xF000); _ms_TVi.state = ((((BOOL fCheck)?2:1) << 12)); SendMessageA((HWND hwndTreeView), (0x1100 + 13), 0, (LPARAM)(TVITEMA *)&_ms_TVi);};
```

It's not what you expect to see in your function declarations.

Both of these [`TreeView_GetCheckState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`TreeView_SetCheckState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760044(v=vs.85).aspx) are standard macroses defined in `CommCtrl.h`. Remove your old functions and use these macroses.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!